# how to make elasticsearch suggest a better search term when the one given is not misspelled?

Tags: elasticsearch

If someone is searching for "kitchen sink" but mistakenly types in "kitchen ink" (which is a valid search and has results), how would I suggest a "did you mean" for "kitchen sink".

I was thinking I could do fuzzy permutations but that might get intensive - eg.  maybe they meant "kitchen pink" or "kitchen link" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [phrase suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html)? That's what it's designed for.